# unable to mock the resttemplate call using restclienttest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, spring-junit

I want to mock my `RestTemplate` which uses `RestTemplateBuilder`. Hence, I am using `restclienttest`.

Unfortunately, I am not able to mock the `resttemplate` call.
when `Sup supExpected = myService.getDetails("1234")` is called, it's performing the complete backend call instead resulting what I have asked to do.

Instead of resulting the custom json string "SD", it is performing actual GET call and giving the response from backend.

Here is my junit code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(MyService.class)
public class TestMyServiceApplication {


    @Autowired
    private MyService myService; 

     @Autowired
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired 
    private MockRestServiceServer server;       

    @Before public void setUp() { 
     server= MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate); }

    @Test
    public void ReturnSupplierSuccessfully() {

        String SD= "{\"SUP\": {\"LNR\": \"1234\",\"NAME1\": \"RestClient\"}]}}";
        this.server
        .expect(requestTo("abc.net/service/v1?lnr=1234"))
        .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
        .andRespond(withSuccess(SD, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        Sup supExpected = myService.getDetails("1234");

        server.verify();
        assertNotNull(supExpected);
    }
```

Can anyone help me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Please attempt the following .  1) Remove the `setUp()` method. 2) modify `requestTo("/service/v1?lnr=1234)`

Comment: @R.G unfortunately that didnt help me. i have redesigned our service class. then it started working .

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `@Mock` annotation on top of RestTemplate and other respective service classes.

```
@Mock
```

Comment: In this case i am using @ restclienttest , inorder to use @ Mok : i have to use mockito framework. 
Since i have RestTemplateBuilder in my service, mockito didn't help me hence i wanted to try with  @ restclienttest